# C# How to allow NEW LINE and WHITE SPACES in textBox

Tags: c#, user-interface, textbox, newline, whitespace

I am trying to write a string in a C# textBox by pressing a button. When I press the button my string should be added in the textBox. However, the string  is added, but the "\n" is completely ignored. How can I allow it?

This is a very simple example that I have written only to understand where the problem is, but I noticed that the same thing happens with white spaces when I am trying to redirect my console output to a textBox.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String s = "first line";
            s += "\n"; 
            s += "second line";
            Console.Out.WriteLine(s);
            textBox1.AppendText(s);
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

how i call it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

[image: output in console and output in textBox]

Comment: Is it possible that you forgot to set `textBox1.Multiline = true`?

Comment: I've checked it and it is set to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\r\n` or `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: It works with \r\n on this example. Thank you.